# Gunicorn's pythonpath error

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

When starting python web application using gunicorn command, like `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8080`.

It prompts cannot find packages like numpy which ran default Python interpreter. I added `pythonpath` to `gunicorn` command, but it doesn't work.  BTW, I created a virtual env in the application folder.

Hope someone could provide a solution.

Comment: Please provide stack trace, what happens when you do import numpy in the python shell etc.

Comment: Did you also activate the Virtualenv most people forget to activate it.

Comment: And also provide the app directory and main app runner code snippet.

Comment: what is the default Python interpreter?

Comment: yes, it's caused by virtual env, and it's solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using default python to execute gunicorn. Either you activate your virtualenv and then execute the `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8080` or else you can use the following command

```
/ABSOLUTE_PATH/vitual_python_env/bin/gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: Cool.  I actually did use default gunicorn in /usr/local while the code project uses a separate virtual env.

Comment: Cool.  I actually did use default gunicorn in /usr/local while the code project uses a separate virtual env.